# How to implement trackbar like this image - Android?

Tags: android, seekbar, trackbar

Please help me implement this view.
Clicking circles brings up mouse over of actual value of min/max/target.
Bar length don't according to any thing.
But bar color's according to target circle. 
Thanks a lot
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom SeekBar. Here is [a tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-seekbar-your-way/943) to get you started.

Comment: but this has 3 circle buttons, and 3 buttons can moving